# Convert discrete number of figures into animation using FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm trying to start a new initiative for my algorithms course.

I want to design a python code that get vertexes, edges and algorithm name as input, and run the algorithm over the graph as an output.

I've created a graph using networkx and already wrote some algorithms.

The script is working in the following steps:

1. it creates a list of networkx graphs.
2. it outputs the graphs as figures.

I wish to change step #2 from photos to animation in order to attract more attention.

The problem is that all the examples/tutorials that I've found relies on the fact that the data is continuous (for instance, drawing a graph), while my data is a discrete amount of networkx graphs.

```py
def print_graph2(Graphs): #Graphs - a list of networkx graphs.
    for index, graph in enumerate(Graphs):
        plt.figure(index + 1)
        pos = nx.bipartite_layout(graph, [node for ind, node in enumerate(graph.nodes) if ind < len(graph.nodes) / 2])
        nx.draw(graph, pos)
        vertex_weight = {u: f'{u}:{w["weight"]}' for u, w in graph.nodes.data()}
        nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos, labels=vertex_weight)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This statement `the data is continuous (for instance, drawing a graph), while my data is a discrete amount of networkx graphs.` is a bit confusing. Can you please ellaborate more on this ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a generator to loop through your list of graphs each time that `FuncAnimation` calls the `func` function. for example:

```
import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib

# create a list of 50 random cycle graphs with nodes ranging from 10 to 100 (the list of your graphs)
graphs = [nx.cycle_graph(random.randint(10, 100)) for g in range(50)]

# make a generator 
def get_a_nice_graph():
    for g in graphs:
        yield g

nice_graph = get_a_nice_graph()

# make the function to pass to FuncAnimation method
def draw_next_graph(n):
    G = next(nice_graph)  # here your call the next graph in the list
    plt.cla()
    plt.title('frame {}'.format(n))  # each graph is a new frame
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, iterations=200)
    nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=range(len(G.nodes)), node_size=100)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), draw_next_graph, 50)
ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Then you will have the following animation:
[image]

**EDIT**: I forgot to call and assign the generator before calling the `next()` method. Now it's corrected.